# Browser close event in .net

Tags: .net

is there any way to find the browser close event in asp.net

Comment: any method, is sketchy at best.  I wouldn't make any critical code reliant on getting that notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Javascript for that.

```
document.unLoad()
```

Answer (score 1):

**For client side event:** use unload event.

**For server side event:**

1. Use unload event to make an Ajax call to the server.
2. Use the session_end event. (I not sure how much this feature is trusted).